Java Heap Space when running QuestDB on Docker
I am running QuestDB 8.1.4 with default parameters via Docker. I can see the message Java Heap Space, 36, ERROR appearing frequently on the logs.
Once the error happens all other processes are stuck and I need to restart the DB.
I should have plenty of memory, as the host has 384GB of RAM, but the QuestDB container seems to be ignoring that.
How can I increase the memory available for QuestDB?

The Docker entry file for the QuestDB official image has a setting to prepend parameters to the JVM.
It should be possible to increase heap memory available by doing something like
docker run -e JVM_PREPEND="-Xmx30g" questdb/questdb

On startup, one of the first log lines of the container should inform that the setting was found and passed to the JVM.
